# Blender 2.8 - how do I make a texture reflect light?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a marble texture that I would like to make shiny.  Roughness is currently set to zero, but there is no light reflection.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Diffuse shader is just what the name suggests, diffuse. Try using a principled shader or combining a diffuse with a glossy shader through a mix shader node.:)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reflection because you are using a diffuse shader. Diffuse shaders have zero reflections, and you need to mix it with a glossy shader to put them on.  There's a simpler and more realistic way to do this, though.  just add a principled shader node and  connect the texture to it the way you connected it to the diffuse.  if you want more info on why you shoud use the principled shader versus a diffuse and glossy mix, Blender Guru has a great youtube tutorial on it.
I hope this helps!

Comment: I suggest you watch the video as it explains every slider on the shader.

Comment: when I try glossy (compared to diffuse) shader, everything goes much darker except the illuminated part of the texture.  Is that normal?

Comment: which youtube video?  https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+guru+shader

Comment: it's the one called " How to Use Blender s New Ultimate Shader - The Principled BSDF"  and yes, it is normal to have the material darker when using a glossy shader versus a diffuse.